# Scraping javascript of CDN data with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, cdn

There is a large dataset, full of neatly-stored tabular data, found [here](https://c0cre127.caspio.com/dp/311a1000697d9171cc1c4128ae42) that I would like to parse through and save locally.

The problem is, no matter how deep I "drill down" to inspect the source code, there isn't any actual data, nor any discernible source page.

My question is, is it therefore even possible to access the data via the typical `requests.get()` and `.content` etc.? Or would something like `selenium` do the trick? If not these two options, then what?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inspecting the page, it's making a POST request https://c0cre127.caspio.com/dp/311a1000697d9171cc1c4128ae42'. Also what you get back is in a structured format. You can see it in the preview within the request in network tools. Interesting the 'responseText' which gives you the data, is all in html. So theoretically you could just parse this part of the data to grab what you need. The problem is when I recreate this HTTP request, the APPKey which is data needed according to the request, says it's wrong. So selenium would work, not sure I can do much about the APPKey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my comment for what it's worth here's the request that should work but doesn't... For reasons I'm not sure, unless there's security at their end with regard to cookies.

Inspecting the page, it's making a POST request to `c0cre127.caspio.com/dp/311a1000697d9171cc1c4128ae42`. Also what you get back is in a structured format. You can see it in the preview within the request in network tools. Interesting the 'responseText' which gives you the data, is all in html. So theoretically you could just parse this part of the data to grab what you need. The problem is when I recreate this HTTP request, the AppKey which part of the cookie needed according to the request, says it's wrong.

So selenium would work, not sure I can do much about the AppKey.

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'cbParamList': '',
    'cbCookieAccepted': '1',
    'AppKey': '311a1000697d9171cc1c4128ae42',
    'AWSALB': '76fnReAlqLZyJz4gNmSMnGc3oluXMlbsrGwaF+kcm4Rg8fklrjjrxvmez+XxXXg/yDle490fw/MKBNPWCyoGAiihFYgcWQ1RSp0vxSGJHDnfXncHSQuprTjv8Fjk',
    'AWSALBCORS': '76fnReAlqLZyJz4gNmSMnGc3oluXMlbsrGwaF+kcm4Rg8fklrjjrxvmez+XxXXg/yDle490fw/MKBNPWCyoGAiihFYgcWQ1RSp0vxSGJHDnfXncHSQuprTjv8Fjk',
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'c0cre127.caspio.com',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'origin': 'https://c0cre127.caspio.com',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://c0cre127.caspio.com/dp/311a1000697d9171cc1c4128ae42',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

params = (
    ('rnd', '1596940878792'),
)

data = '$------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="cbUniqueFormId"\\r\\n\\r\\n_69831fa53c178f\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="ComparisonType1_1"\\r\\n\\r\\n\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="MatchNull1_1"\\r\\n\\r\\nN\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="FieldName2"\\r\\n\\r\\nDate\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Operator2"\\r\\n\\r\\nOR\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="NumCriteriaDetails2"\\r\\n\\r\\n1\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="ComparisonType2_1"\\r\\n\\r\\n=\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="MatchNull2_1"\\r\\n\\r\\nN\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="FieldName3"\\r\\n\\r\\n\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Operator3"\\r\\n\\r\\n\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="NumCriteriaDetails3"\\r\\n\\r\\n1\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="ComparisonType3_1"\\r\\n\\r\\n\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="MatchNull3_1"\\r\\n\\r\\nN\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="FieldName4"\\r\\n\\r\\nProperty\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Operator4"\\r\\n\\r\\nOR\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="NumCriteriaDetails4"\\r\\n\\r\\n1\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="ComparisonType4_1"\\r\\n\\r\\n=\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="MatchNull4_1"\\r\\n\\r\\nN\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="FieldName5"\\r\\n\\r\\n\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Operator5"\\r\\n\\r\\n\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="NumCriteriaDetails5"\\r\\n\\r\\n1\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="ComparisonType5_1"\\r\\n\\r\\n\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="MatchNull5_1"\\r\\n\\r\\nN\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="FieldName6"\\r\\n\\r\\nZone\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Operator6"\\r\\n\\r\\nOR\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="NumCriteriaDetails6"\\r\\n\\r\\n1\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="ComparisonType6_1"\\r\\n\\r\\n=\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="MatchNull6_1"\\r\\n\\r\\nN\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="AppKey"\\r\\n\\r\\n311a1000697d9171cc1c4128ae42\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="PrevPageID"\\r\\n\\r\\n1\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="cbPageType"\\r\\n\\r\\nSearch\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="PageID"\\r\\n\\r\\n2\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="GlobalOperator"\\r\\n\\r\\nAND\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="NumCriteria"\\r\\n\\r\\n6\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Search"\\r\\n\\r\\n1\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Value2_1"\\r\\n\\r\\n04/05/2020\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Value4_1"\\r\\n\\r\\nAtterbury\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Value6_1"\\r\\n\\r\\nCentral\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="ClientQueryString"\\r\\n\\r\\n\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="AjaxAction"\\r\\n\\r\\nSearchForm\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="GridMode"\\r\\n\\r\\nFalse\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="cbUniqueFormId"\\r\\n\\r\\n_69831fa53c178f\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="AjaxActionHostName"\\r\\n\\r\\nhttps://c0cre127.caspio.com\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="cbAjaxReferrer"\\r\\n\\r\\nhttps://c0cre127.caspio.com/dp/311a1000697d9171cc1c4128ae42\\r\\n------WebKitFormBoundarykaIBnhjgBEZ0L714--\\r\\n'

response = requests.post('https://c0cre127.caspio.com/dp/311a1000697d9171cc1c4128ae42', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies, data=data)
```

### Output

```
'Undefined AppKey. (<a href="http://www.caspio.com/l/default.ashx?s=157">Caspio Bridge</a> error) (60011)'
```

### Update

[image]

Comment: This is a very thorough approach! Thank you for posting. Quick question....Where did you find the params or headers? I was able to find those cookies easily enough via a r.cookies.items(), but how did you manage to find the exact headers and params?

Comment: All the information is within the network tools of Chrome Dev Tools. So I opened network tools, did a search on the website to record the HTTP request needed to get the data. If I need to mimic requests I will copy the request in CURL form as can be seen in the picture. But all the information is there in the right hand box. I use http://curl.trillworks.com to convert it into python.

Comment: @Jkiefn1 : That's a lot of work there by AaronS. Be sure to "thank him" by accepting his answer and/or upvoting. Good luck to all.